# Why does this simple continued fraction evaluate to a modified Bessel function on WolframAlpha? (without proof)

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, continued-fractions, wolfram-alpha

I was curious to find out the value of the first continued fraction constant $C_1$ (a non-repeating simple continuous fraction) as it obviously wouldn't be the root of a quadratic (due to it not repeating):

$$C_1 = \overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\LARGE{\textrm{K}}}} ~ \frac{1}{n} = \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}}$$

Still, it shocked me to see WolframAlpha use modified Bessel functions. According to WolframAlpha, $\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\textrm{K}}} \, \frac{1}{n} = \frac{I_1(2)}{I_0(2)} \approx 0{,}697775$. I would've loved to find some sort of proof, but unfortunately these types of questions are hard to search for online. The only resource I could find other than [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_constants#Mathematical_constants_sorted_by_their_representations_as_continued_fractions) or Mathworld was this French article from [Numdam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_constants#Mathematical_constants_sorted_by_their_representations_as_continued_fractions).

[Here is a screenshot of the command 'continued fraction K (1, n, {n, 1, inf})'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgGpe.png)

[Here is the actual link to the calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued%20fraction%20K%20%281%2C%20n%2C%20%7Bn%2C%201%2C%20inf%7D%29)

As a high school student I know next to nothing about the modified Bessel functions, but just for reference $I_n(x)$ is one of the two families of functions (another is $K_n(x)$) that satisfy the modified Bessel ODE $$x^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} - (x^2 + n^2)y = 0$$

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html

It might be helpful to include series representations of $I_0(x)$ and $I_1(x)$: $$I_0(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k}{(k!)^2}} \textsf{ and } I_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} x \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{4}x^2 \right)^k}{k!(k+1)!}}$$

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

In fact, according to a MathWorld article on [Continued Fraction Constants](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstants.html), it claims that the numerator of the nth convergent $A_n$ and the denominator $B_n$ both satisfy the recurrence relationship $T_{n+1} = T_n + T_{n-1}$ which [according to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28n%2B2%29%20%3D%20nf%28n%2B1%29%20%2B%20f%28n%29) has the solution $T_n = c_1 I_{n-1}(-2) + c_2 K_{n-1}(2)$, which is also surprising. Unfortunately no proof was provided, which is a big flaw of WolframAlpha. It would be great if anyone could explain any of the recursions, as $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{A_n}{B_n}} = C_1$.

**Update 1**
Thanks for Function and Gerry Myerson's link to D. H. Lehmer's paper. I am stuck on the first step, which apparently easily follows from the definition of $I_n(x) = \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}x^2 \right)^k}{k!(k+n)!}}$. Here's my working:

$$\begin{align} I_{n-1}(x) &\overset{?}{=} \frac{2n}{x} I_n(x) + I_{n+1}(x) \\ \text{RHS} &= \left[ \frac{2n}{x} \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^n \sum{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n)!}} \right] + \left( \frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n+1} \sum{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n+1)!}} \\ &= \left[ n \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \sum{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n)!}} \right] + \left( \frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n+1} \sum{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n+1)!}} \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1}  \left[ n \sum{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n)!}}  + \left( \frac{1}{2}x \right)^2 \sum{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n+1)!}} \right] \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \sum{ \left[ \frac{n \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n)!}  + \frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k+1} }{k!(k+n+1)!} \right] } \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \left[ \frac{n}{n!} + \sum{ \frac{n \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k+1} }{(k+1)!(k+n+1)!}  + \frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k+1} }{k!(k+n+1)!}  } \right] \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \left[ \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{(k + n + 1) \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k+1} }{(k+1)!(k+n+1)!}  } \right] \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \left[ \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{ \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k+1} }{(k+1)!(k+n)!}  } \right] \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \left[ \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{ \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k} }{k!(k+n-1)!}  } \right] \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{ \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k} }{k!(k+n - 1)!}  } = \text{LHS} \end{align}$$

**Update 2**
Thanks to Function's help, this recursion *does* in fact "easily" come from the definition of $I_n(x)$. I've fixed my working.

$$\begin{align}  \end{align}$$

Comment: A proof is given here: https://oeis.org/A016825/a016825.pdf

Comment: Wow, this is great! I forgot to look at OEIS. Cheers mate.

Comment: More generally, if the partial quotients form an arithmetic progression (with nonzero common difference), then the fraction can be expressed in terms of Bessel functions. This was shown in a paper by D H Lehmer, "Continued fractions containing arithmetic progressions".

Comment: @Function For some reason can't seem to solve the 'simple' recurrence relation $I_{n-1}(z) = \frac{2n}{z} I_n(z) + I_{n+1}(z)$ which is the first step in the proof. I've tried to search for it online but they all give it as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: You got it right. In the 4th row after "RHS", the second term can be merged into the first term by a shift of indices k + 1 --> k.

Comment: @Function I've tried to change summation indexes, but I just can't seem to simplify things. Can you please show me the steps that you would do?

Comment: \begin{align*}
             &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^k }{k!(k+n)!}  + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k+1} }{k!(k+n+1)!} \right] \\
             &= \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)^{n-1} \left[ \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(n +k+1)\left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 \right)^{k+1} }{(k+1)!(k+1+n)!} \right]
\end{align*}

Comment: Find a proof here: Problem solution E3264 in 
*American Mathematical Monthly*, **97** (1990) p.157